# CoverletOutputFormat vstest.console

Tags: .net, code-coverage, github-actions, coveralls, vstest.console

I need to set up Coveralls. Before this I am trying to set up `/p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov` with `vstest.console`.
So I am successfully using `dotnet test  --results-directory "./testresults" -l trx -c Release /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov` to set `CoverletOutputFormat` with `dotnet test` command. This case is working.

But currently I need to use it for `dotnet vstest`

My full command is:
`vstest.console MyFolder\MyDll.dll  /ResultsDirectory:"./testresults" /Logger:trx /EnableCodeCoverage /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov`
The output is: `The argument /p:CoverletOutputFormat=lcov is invalid`

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

`vstest.console MyFolder\MyDll.dll /ResultsDirectory:"./testresults" /Logger:trx /EnableCodeCoverage --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" -- DataCollectionRunSettings.DataCollectors.DataCollector.Configuration.Format=lcov`

---

**Option 2**

Use the following command and runsettings file:

`vstest.console MyFolder\MyDll.dll /ResultsDirectory:"./testresults" /Logger:trx /EnableCodeCoverage /Settings:CodeCoverage.runsettings`

`CodeCoverage.runsettings`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="XPlat Code Coverage">
        <Configuration>
          <Format>lcov</Format>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```